# “array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token” with extern const size definition

Tags: c++, constants, extern

I am trying something like this:

```
// def.cpp
extern const uint16_t array_size = 4U;
```

```
// use.hpp
extern const uint16_t array_size;

class myClass_WithArray
{
    uint16_t myArray[array_size];
};
```

Somewhere of course an object is created.
But what I get in the header is the compiler error:

```
error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

What is the problem here? If I put the definition of the constant in the same header, everything is working fine. It seems to be a linkage error?

Comment: If the definition of `array_size` is not visible to the compiler when it is compiling `uint16_t myArray[array_size];`, then the compiler does not know what the value is, and it does not qualify as an integer constant. The value would only be known when the module that defines `array_size` is linked to the module that defines `myArray`, and then it is too late—the array must have been already defined, with a complete size, when the module defining it was compiled.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, it will not be working like this in general: the size cannot be defined in the first compilation unit, as the second compilation unit will not be compiling and the linkage will never happen. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.